# What is difference between these 2 EF queries ? Which is best and why?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

What is difference between these 2 queries in EF, which is best and why?

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    var blogs = (from b in context.Blogs select b).ToList(); 

    var blogs = context.Blogs.ToList(); 
}
```

Comment: Another way to compare Linq to EF queries when in doubt is to do `.ToString()` on the queries. This will give you the SQL the query was translated to. In this case it should be identical.

Comment: Why you downvoted my question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally Agreed with @Habib right answer courtesy @Habib

**Remember I copied from @Habib**

I believe your question is about Method Syntax vs Query Syntax. Your first query is based on Query Syntax and the second one is based on Method syntax.

See: [Query Syntax and Method Syntax in LINQ (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx)

Most queries in the introductory Language Integrated Query (LINQ) documentation are written by using the LINQ declarative query syntax. However, the query syntax must be translated into method calls for the .NET common language runtime (CLR) when the code is compiled.

EDIT: With your edited code snippets, there is no difference between two queries at the time of execution. Your first query is based on query syntax which will compile into method syntax (your second query). To select between those two is a matter of choice. I personally finds method syntax more readable.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your question is about Method Syntax vs Query Syntax. Your first query is based on Query Syntax and the second one is based on Method syntax.

See: [Query Syntax and Method Syntax in LINQ (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx)

> Most queries in the introductory Language Integrated Query (LINQ)
>   documentation are written by using the LINQ declarative query syntax.
>   However, the query syntax must be translated into method calls for the
>   .NET common language runtime (CLR) when the code is compiled.

EDIT: 
With your edited code snippets, there is no difference between two queries at the time of execution. Your first query is based on query syntax which will compile into method syntax (your second query). To select between those two is a matter of choice. I personally finds method syntax more readable.

Old Answer:

---

**However,There is a major difference between your two queries.**  Your first query is just a query construct, It hasn't been executed,considering that you have tagged Entity framework, Your first query will not bring any records from database in memory. To iterate the result set you need `ToList()`, `ToArray()` etc.

Your second query is infact getting all the records from your table and loading in a `List<T>` object in memory.

Also see: [Deferred query execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738633(v=vs.100).aspx)

> In a query that returns a sequence of values, the query variable
>   itself never holds the query results and only stores the query
>   commands. Execution of the query is deferred until the query variable
>   is iterated over in a foreach or For Each loop. This is known as
>   deferred execution; that is, query execution occurs some time after
>   the query is constructed. This means that you can execute a query as
>   frequently as you want to. This is useful when, for example, you have
>   a database that is being updated by other applications. In your
>   application, you can create a query to retrieve the latest information
>   and repeatedly execute the query, returning the updated information
>   every time.

Comment: I Update the Question Now both Quries will return the same results

Comment: @WaqasIdrees, in this case just concentrate on the first part of my answer. It is Method syntax vs Query syntax. There is no difference between your **updated** queries. Query syntax query (first one) will compile into method syntax.

Answer (score 0):

First query doesn't perform anything, you are just constructing the query.

Second query fetches all the blog records from DB and load them into memory.

Which is best is depends on your needs.

**Edit:** If you are asking for syntax, there is no difference.The query syntax will be compiled into extension method calls by the compiler.

Apart from that, this:

```
from b in context.Blogs select b
```

is kinda *pointless*. It's equivelant to `context.Blogs.Select(x => x)`. So in this case I would go with  `context.Blogs.ToList();`